# C# Socket binding to wrong interface

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, udpclient

The problem I am encountering is that my sockets are not binding to the correct interface. I tried this with an UDPClient and an Socket directly.

I have 2 available interfaces with the adresses 192.168.1.38 and 10.5.0.2, where the second one is my VPN. The VPN does allow local network discovery (i.e. I can ping my laptop on 192.168.1.165), but my sockets only bind on the vpn interface. Both the following code samples create a Socket with LocalEndPoint 10.5.0.2:11000

Using Socket:

```
        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.38"), 11000);
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        socket.Bind(endpoint);
```

Using UDPClient:

```
        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.38"), 11000);
        var c = new UdpClient(endpoint);
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Could you check with `netstat -abnp UDP` that the socket is really bound to the wrong interface?

Comment: @Heinzi It seems like it is bound to the wrong interface, but also a different port:
  "UDP    10.5.0.2:52791         *:*
  SSDPSRV"
What does SSDPSRV mean in this case?

Comment: Good question, no idea, sorry.

Comment: @Heinzi correction, I read the output wrong previously. The output actually is: "UDP    10.5.0.2:11000         \*:\*". So it has the correct port but is bound to the wrong interface